# Sort array based on conditions of the array to avoid near candidates

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, shuffle

I am building an application in where from a list of childs with properties and based on different criterias, it sorted randomly in a classroom of 5 columns. The application has been made in Angular, so I want to manage how to sort an array based on different conditions (no the simplest ones, based on the nearest values-taking into account the below(+5) and above(-5)).

I have the following function to shuffle the array, which works fine:

```
function shuffle(array: Child[]): Child[] {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
     const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
     [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
  return array;
}
```

However it is not what I am looking for. I upload an image to show the goal and the problem. Here it is a list with the childs sorted in different tables:
[image: class]

As can be seen in the picture, the list of childs are sorted in different tables, but they have some codes below the names based on the needs (A, V, H). I am looking for sorting the childs based on the H, which is a property of the array (boolean). In case one child has H, which means true, it cannot be near other child with H true.

What I am trying is looking in the array the position +5(below), -5(above), +1(next), -1(previous) to get the following usage. For example, in the picture, david could not be near to amelia, since both have the property h and are near enough. So the easiest would be to change amelia for jaime, who has no one near (left,right,above,below) with the property H and amanda by juan and the class would be properly sorted:
[image]

I am trying with the following function with no luck, but maybe there is somethig easier to perform this operation which I am missing.

```
  public checkSites(array: Child[], index: number): boolean {
    if (array[index].talk){
      if(index > 4 && array[index - 5].talk){
        return true
      }
      else if(index > 0 && array[index - 1].talk){
        return true
      }
      else if(index < array.length - 1 && array[index + 1].talk){
        return true
      }
      else if(index < array.length - 5 && array[index + 5].talk){
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Which is called from the following function:

```
this.childs.forEach((value, index) => {
  if(value.talk && this.checkSites(this.childs, index)){
     //TODO
  }
})
```

But the aproximation which I am taking is not the correct since it is not working as expected, so the question is, how could I do a function to check those positions and in case of the near has the property suffle that child with another child without the property and no one with the property near?

I let an example here, taking as initial the example provided by
jcalz: [typescriptlang](https://www.typescriptlang.org/es/play?#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-qIC76rsXZaXs+WEwIQERazro4qfV7FbH4jm5plOMtU02+yWjS346aOp8EPooOOZViG-bp1nca3TWywCRNZ6S1OmzOd3O3R9gIIwOQSGBV4W7fL1+eppfRYtiSm13qoxGmb0rOTJugAwsSvwiE+9anm+24ftgAC62APpo+hKMACAwGBpAUMw9jMtAxLqtM4Y8J8IAgIgIjTKelHUQgtH2EaDE0WA2DWLgiCwGACAAO4APpJsmACePC4WQ5A0Eh1AyTg2AKLewA3DA94QAADlqokABTEFJEASXh0lIQAlARDD4BAjEAHRwCAOR6cZEA2ewrAaTpOnkBIJDmSgAB80KeSQMAAKTwEg5kAPwwAARLFMA8LFAA6YCxeZADUcU0AlWXkDZswwFlXk2bUMAxbFAC0lUJUlcWZXFSHpTZABWIAPjp8WmaZOBcdgAD0-UAPLEjkD7KGU+hiXg4DWYgdkOZ1Q3pAAkgA4itABybRmulM2QLZ9mOfpFAQKZA39W8RCCAoCiIJNYkwPtc0IAtjmxRA123Yge2fTdd0IE5BnnVZh2LSdlDnYNMAACpDSyQ08MQCDAGYMAaSAsg3FQIjkDAxAiBqJhEAg7C4KD81HTp52oQoMBA6ddlIDkUBEDAACEKBoIgyAAFQRWA5ms54-EwHxotilNID6J1bKmDAMgwN85DpQpSlgCpOhiyAMPmA+jnkBorBGVJMkSDe+gmxQMlyWZVsmTAAA+MC3uQCAKA+7gWQrdM6ezhumEz6qs+Z3RQII+jIBbOAMGHEdR0QVGqF5RsSF5EjdNAfn+d7lmzbAcDUBbQcs0QMeMCQvuF-5aAAIwwAAZA3amleYjfNxbNCF5VMC10hrcxKHCDh5HLt3u7nvkOXDCV-T1fc0g7ct2VTf4xHXcwD3PP97UQ8j8grsT3xU-QnHo+PrrMT6zpmdQBINA2Y-FsSOQZnl9Y519VZsAiYT7hvCATaOs9bqmoBfEBx1nI9VwLPP2v91T-0AcAq+6pzJMHsBTV6VNYorXmC4Iabw3grQAEJmjFKrTiMBNSqG9pgt6nV0hijaOkdIbRNprTFCyPaDB1JaVYLpeBGpyAAKAZfMw+toF9WhsjVGPsxZMX0PjZyAocZ3mJthLGGjE5VjxouJRf9yCKWUqpGRZgxHwk0BAHSv9xI4WMmbBW48AAePAwCCHYIufQpkKJUXYt7WBNiaAPjdk4ne5hTLoKSJXHSwSEBOJgDnAALEvQJsT4k93QGEwekSkgwDPsgNY0IuJJGodhaJaSEkwAAAwpKmvwoJzjN69yyWYCJ0JY7D3jgqBARToSlJ9jExpAAeB6-CS6syafXVeqTGlZT7gPVpOSkj5O6b0kpkQBkVJGTY8ZbMMm1LEg0kJRUMAtLabkvJnTR6FKSNYKhGylmMBWWiNZMA7n9Mec8+I79cBcX6rzXm9B+ZXX+ogHGdTRKOPRlqLCNkYBijeAANikEufoQKYAAAENJJg4MwIkYk7msAVpodgVA8yjMhfgUwD59bqOJaTFyQL+pGI1qpP631AY2PtjJbxdjTayRyQoaWc9h4K2oDsnmpdJmYDFTnKpMqSDVTQe0-G+cYAtWoIsVmNk7pURllqogNlkx3hAOwamMB+YxJObXbq09GA0FSUhdQEKaAtSQrJNADqXVuudYckg7qfkdP3hS3quAWWa3AEopOCAhkwwkOkfyTl2pYUMrDBxVo4BwG+KjHgSaSBYR4HGy50BC08tQDndITsx5uw9sfXllbnaH1rV7HJ39HH3hTdQfFYyuimp0kwAWpckaJ3zQgFykqJm2HpoJHy2cFbQPsPxPC2FBkdrHbs5VSQ21HLiR69to6XKaWrFhHSBqdX2WlqejQhrjXkD7eZfmwSD0bokDa6Ebaw5F2UFm1gqM80pp3aE82I6U06rIOhTyM753lrFZzNAaTbXQlgZ+uD1aj7uD3l0sOgbLnBqbZPUN2AgA)

Comment: Does "near" mean "adjacent"?   Are diagonals adjacent?

Comment: No diagonals, just above, below, next and previous

Comment: Is your grid/table always 5 columns and `n` rows, with the underlying array starting at the top left and moving RTL then TTB?

Comment: It would help if you'd provide a [mre] that can be pasted into a standalone IDE so that people could work on it without having to write their own data.

Comment: Does something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w14V2W) work for you? The example there is a 3x3 grid with 5 "talk"ers.  The algorithm is a simple constraint solver (the `choose()` function) that takes a list of things to choose from and a callback, and picks things from the list at random until the callback returns a defined value, and returns `undefined` if it runs out of things to choose.  If you call `choose()` recursively you can get a series of choices with backtracking if things fail.  (Note that if you change the data so there are 6 or more "talk"s then it's impossible) ...

Comment: ... If you just "shuffle" after each failure you may end up bouncing around a long time, trying things that won't work over and over.  In the case where the constraints are impossible, any shuffling technique would just run forever without terminating.  Anyway, if the solution linked above meets your needs I can write up an answer; if not, please consider [edit]ing the example code in your question to be a [mre] that demonstrates any use cases left unsatisfied.

Comment: I've added at the end an example to play over there. The idea is to shuffle the array first and then check, and in case no possibilities based on the number of "talk"ers, then let is as better as possible (maybe just two together).